# How to get my search box to pull id too?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a search box in my excel worksheet which searches for users and displays all the matches so if I have `5 x John Smiths` it shows them. I would like it so that it also displays their ID code.

Can anyone advise how to do this? See the image and code below I have so far. The code below is for the selected box in the image F7

`=INDEX($C$3:$C$17,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER((SEARCH($F$3,$C$3:$C$17))*(SEARCH($H$3,$B$3:$B$17))),ROW($B$3:$B$17)-MIN(ROW($B$3:$B$17))+1,""),ROW(A1)))`

[image: screenshot here]

Comment: Can you explain a little more?  You talk about displaying five John Smiths; can you show an example of that, and explain how you do it?  You say you're showing the formula for `F7`, but your screenshot says it is `F8`.  Your formula seems to be searching for `$F$3` and `$H$3`, but it appears from the image that these are the constant labels ``First name`` and `Last name`. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same formula but change the index:
For First Name write in F7:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$3:$C$21,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER((SEARCH($F$3,$C$3:$C$21))*(SEARCH($H$3,$B$3:$B$21))),ROW($B$3:$B$21)-MIN(ROW($B$3:$B$21))+1,""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

For Last Name in G7 use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$21,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER((SEARCH($F$3,$C$3:$C$21))*(SEARCH($H$3,$B$3:$B$21))),ROW($B$3:$B$21)-MIN(ROW($B$3:$B$21))+1,""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

For ID in H7 use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$3:$D$21,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER((SEARCH($F$3,$C$3:$C$21))*(SEARCH($H$3,$B$3:$B$21))),ROW($B$3:$B$21)-MIN(ROW($B$3:$B$21))+1,""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

I used C3:C21 because I added duplicated names to test the formula, Change all references to correspond your Data.

- B3:B21 is Last Name Data
- C3:C21 is First Name Data
- D3:D21 is Id Data

Keep $ for fixed references and for each formula press at the same time <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Enter</kbd> array formula and you can drag it down the column (each formula in its column do not mix it)
It is the same formula but the Index references change to correspond the column Header

[image]

Comment: hmmm i tried this but it didnt seem to work it just stayed blank and didnt give any result if i typed in a  name. But if i left the boxes f3 & h3 blank it would bring up the first name on the list - any ideas?

Comment: You have to write in F3 and H3 the Name exactly like in B and C no added spaces

Comment: Also it is the same formula as yours only the Index column change to pull different result and do not forget to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter at the same time

Comment: thanks i have it kind of working now, where it finds the person you search for which was Andy Murray, however it doesnt find the next Andy Murray it just displays the same person and id over and over.

I tried changing the next line down to have +2 instead of +1 to see if that helped? but that only finds the next person whos directly underneath the first andy murray. What did you do different in the F8, G8 and H8 cells?

Really appreciate the help :)

Comment: can you copy your formula and paste it in the comment?

Comment: The Data you showed does not contain duplicate names (2 times Andy Murray)

Comment: Ive put the code into my invoice system so its all a bit different now and there is duplicate names so it should so a different one. Il try explaining best i can.

B3:B21 is ID, C3:C21 is First NAme, D3:D21 is Last Name, I24 is First Name search box and I25 is last name search box

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX($C$3:$C$21,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER((SEARCH($I$24,$C$3:$C$21))*(SEARCH($I$25,$D$3:$D$21))),ROW($D$3:$D$21)-MIN(ROW($D$3:$D$21))+1,""),ROW(A1))),"")

Comment: that is for the results bit for the first name (basically the F7 cell in your sheet)

Comment: i think its something to do with the next row (Cell F8, G8 and H8 if we use yours as example) not finding the next person called andy murray its just duplicating the first one as code is the same. If i chnage the +1 to =2 thoguh it just gets the person underneath it not the next name in the search

Comment: Its working - my error i copied and pasted the code to next lines didnt drag it down as you mentioned first time......whoops. Big thanks for help!